# ubuntu server refused public-key signature despite accepting key - from putty

Tags: server, ssh, putty

I am a newbie in Ubuntu. I am securing server and did two things:

1. Setup ssh (public / private key using putty)
2. Allow Root Login to no

Now, I can't login with root password and I'm also getting error with private key. I am locked out. I read in some forums/answers, it could be issue related to permission.

My VPS is hosted on ovh.com and I can only do restart in recovery mode. Please help.

Comment: Don't you have other user with sudo access?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `PermitRootLogin no` means that `root` user is not allowed to login regardless authentication method (this is a good practice).

You can weaken this hardening by setting `prohibit-password`, which will block only password authentications and you can still login with private key.

But still the best option is to log in with the non-root user and for privileged actions use `sudo`.

Regardless the options, you need physical access or console access to fix the things up (if you don't have other user to log in with).

Answer (score -1):

You need to change ssh configuration  `AllowRootLogin` Parameter from `No`

to `Yes`.

Comment: or better change it to without-password